# Maximum call stack size exceeded from jquery post form

Tags: php, jquery, html, post

I am in the progress of building a user management system, however I run into a problem with my register form and keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

this is the form html and jquery i am currently using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#login").click(function(){
var process = "login";
var email = $("#loginemail").val();
var password = $("#loginpassword").val();
if($('#remember').is(':checked')) {
var remember = '1';
}
 
$.post("process.php", {process: process,email: email,password: password,remember: remember}, function(result){
    
 if(result === 'Login Successful!'){
  document.location.href = 'index.php';
 }
 else{
 $("#response").html(result);
 $("#response").show();
 }
});
return false;
});

$("#register").click(function(){
var process = "register";
var username = $("#regusername").val();
var email = $("#regemail").val();
var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
var password = $("#regpassword").val();
var conpassword = $("#conregpassword").val();
$.post("process.php",{process:process,username:username,email:email,firstname:firstname,lastname:lastname,password:password,conpassword:conpassword}, function(result){
    $("#response").html(result);
 $("#response").show();
});
return false;
});

$("#registerlink").click(function(){
$("#response").hide();
$(".loginform").slideToggle( "slow" );
$(".registerform").slideToggle( "slow" );
return false;
});

$("#loginlink").click(function(){
$("#response").hide();
$(".registerform").slideToggle( "slow" );
$(".loginform").slideToggle( "slow" );
return false;
});

});
```

```html
<form class="registerform" method="post" action="#">
<h2>Register</h2>
<label>Username :</label>
<input type="text" name="regusername" id="regusername" placeholder="Username" required>
<label>Email :</label>
<input type="text" name="regemail" id="regemail" placeholder="Email" required>
<label>Real Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First" required>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last" required>
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="regpassword" id="regpassword" placeholder="Password" required>
<label>Confirm Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="conregpassword" id="conregpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
<input type="button" name="register" id="register" value="Register">
<span>Already have an account? <a href="#" id="loginlink">Login here!</a></span>
</form>
```

```
function register($username,$email,$first,$last,$password,$conpassword){
global $con;

if(isset($username)){
    if(strlen($username < 5)){
        echo 'Username must be at least 5 characters long!';
        exit;
    }
    if(!preg_match('/^\w{5,}$/', $username)) { // \w equals "[0-9A-Za-z_]"
         echo 'Invalid Username!';
        exit;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'Username already in use!';
    exit;
    }
}

if(isset($email)){
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           echo("$email is an invalid email address");
        exit;
     }
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
$query = $con->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'Email Address already in use!';
    exit;
    }
}
if($password != $conpassword){
    echo 'Passwords dont match!';
    exit;
}

$password = md5($password);
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
$secureString = md5($randomString);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, verified, verify_code, first, last) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '0', '".$secureString."', '".$first."', '".$last."')";
$query = $con->query($sql);

if($query){
    //send email
    $to = $email;
    $subject = 'Email Verification';
    $from = 'admin@curious-coders.com';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Create email headers
    $headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // Compose a simple HTML email message
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<h1>Hi '.$username.'!</h1>';
    $message .= '<p>Thank you for registering with us!</p>';
    $message .= '<p>In order to verify your email address and activate your account, please <a href="http://development.curious-coders.com/login/verify.php?token='.$secureString.'">click here</a></p>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    // Sending email
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
         echo 'A verification email has been sent to '.$to.'!';
        exit;
    }
    else{
         echo 'Unable to send verification email. Please try again.';
        exit;
    }
}
```

}

I have searched around, and hear a lot about recurring functions creating endless loop but I can't seem to spot it in my code, I must be overlooking something.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error should show a line number and the file where the error occurs. Are you sure that it is in this part of your script. I don't see anything that would cause this error in there.

Comment: The error itself describes something like this: ```(function a(){a();})();``` and is to prevent crashes caused by this.

Comment: @Liam Allan do u hv other js code in the page ?

Comment: i edited post and added the full js, this is location of error 'at Vc (jquery.min.js:5)'

Comment: The error is in a PHP file, you've only posted JS and HTML files.

Comment: see, i didnt think of that as it was jquery throwing the error, but you have a point. i added php to the post